# Some parts of my mesh getting see through when i zoom or change the view angle

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

Some parts of my mesh getting see through when i zoom or change the view angle in edit mode.

tried change clip distance but nothing change

[image]

[image: zoom a bit]

enter image description here
[image: some artefacts]

[image: normals looks ok]

[image]

[image]